# Is there a Mac RSS reader which shows unreads in the dock menu

Tags: mac, software-recommendation, dock, rss

I've been a user of NetNewsWire as my RSS reader for god knows how long...  it must be over ten years.  Alas when it changed hands the new developer removed my favourite feature - showing the unread articles in a hierarchical menu in the dock.  That feature allows the user to very quickly scan the unreads, especially if you have your feeds arranged into many folders/topics.

[image: NetNewsWire's dock menu]

I have become addicted to this feature - so much so that I'm still using NNW version 3.  I would like to move to a new RSS reader that will continue to be maintained and has sync features so that I can use an RSS reader on my iPad.

However - the new application must have the dock menu feature.  I cannot find such an app.  Does anyone know if such an app exists?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't offer another solution, but would suggest that you provide feedback to the new developer (if you haven't already) so that he/she is aware of how much this feature was used. If enough people give the same feedback, they may reintroduce this feature. As an aside, I may check out NNW v3 on the basis of your question! :)

Comment: Thanks - I have done.  I didn't get a reply.  I suspect that it's not as popular a feature with others as it is with me (thus the seeming lack of alternative apps.)

Comment: Well, I think it sounds like a great feature (not that I've used it yet). So I may just have to provide similar feedback! :)

Comment: Make your own! :D I also recommend feeder.co's RSS Feed Reader chrome extension that has this feature (just on the menubar of Chrome)